# IntelliJ Crashes on opening Gradle project, why?

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, intellij-idea, tomcat9

So I have been using IntelliJ with Gradle perfectly fine for the past few days. I tried to create a second Gradle project in the same workspace and since, IntelliJ crashes when i open it. The start screen appears, the project opens then a few seconds later it just closes. There is a crash report that appears, which is attached.

I tried deleting the new project and just opening the old one but it made no difference. It seems to be happening permanently now. I even tried reinstalling IntelliJ but it had the same problem the moment I created a second project.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

[Log File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/170bYcIPP-PsgTti-U6aXbwJA2jZfuHln/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Which Java version are you using to run IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @yole JDK 1.8.0_162

Comment: Are there any java crash logs in your user home directory (files with names like `java_error_in_idea_*.log`)? Make sure to run IDE under the bundled JRE, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879 If issue remains, [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) with java crash logs and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) file attached after IDE restart and reproducing.

Comment: @Andrey Yes these log files are there. Should I contact support then?

Comment: What OS are you using? This seems to be happening to me on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Akavall I am using Windows 10. I ended up clean installing IntelliJ and it all worked fine. The problem was with the JDK Versioning. This worked for me: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under It explains installing Java 8 properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a look around and being very close to contacting support, I found a post (I cannot find where) that suggested these errors are to do with my JDK version. After following [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) tutorial, the problem was fixed. Hope this helps someone else with the same issues!